# How to get field from postgres jsonb nested array

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb column in my table.
There is a data

```json
[
   {
      "name":"Гарнир",
      "num_max":1,
      "num_min":1,
      "modifications":[
         {
            "name":"Салат Вінегрет",
            "price":48,
            "brutto":1,
            "ingredient_id":33,
            "dish_modification_id":1
         },
         {
            "name":"Картошка фри",
            "price":24,
            "brutto":150,
            "ingredient_id":28,
            "dish_modification_id":2
         },
         {
            "name":"Говядина",
            "price":54,
            "brutto":150,
            "ingredient_id":19,
            "dish_modification_id":22
         },
         {
            "name":"Соус «Цезарь»",
            "price":27.6,
            "brutto":50,
            "ingredient_id":6,
            "dish_modification_id":23
         }
      ],
      "dish_modification_group_id":1
   },
   {
      "name":"Напитки",
      "num_max":1,
      "num_min":1,
      "modifications":[
         {
            "name":"Десерт Alphonso",
            "price":66,
            "brutto":1,
            "ingredient_id":11,
            "dish_modification_id":9
         }
      ],
      "dish_modification_group_id":4
   }
]
```

I need to get "price" field by product_id (integer table field) and "dish_modification_id".
How to do it?

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: Can you please **[edit]** your question and add the output you expect?

Comment: Are you familiar with https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using posgres 13.1 (latest hub.docker image). What do you mean by output? I need only one column with one filed "price"

Comment: @Bergi, yes, I am familiar with it, but don't understand hot to query nested array

Comment: Do you only want a single price for a specific array item? Or all of them? And if you want all of them, do you need other columns (=keys) from that array as well. A sample result table of what you expect would help. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: @nomvd Use a join against a subquery with `jsonb_array_elements`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I need only one price value get by specific dish_modificatin_id and product_id (which is outside jsonb array). 
Here is request example, which is not working of course 
`select (jsonb_array_elements(modification_groups->'modifications'->'dish_modification_id' ='1'))::text as t from menu where product_id = 177;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. You can of course add a `where` and other clauses.

```sql
with t(x) as 
(
 select j from jsonb_array_elements('... put your JSON data here ...'::jsonb) j
)
select (e ->> 'price')::numeric, (e ->> 'dish_modification_id')::numeric 
  from t 
 cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(t.x -> 'modifications') e;
```

Another (maybe cleaner) version. First flatten and then select.

```sql
with t(jsondata) as 
(
 select '... put your JSON data here ...'::jsonb
)
 select (e ->> 'price')::numeric, (e ->> 'dish_modification_id')::numeric 
   from t 
  cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(jsondata) ext_array
  cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(ext_array -> 'modifications') e;
```

Running examples [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oasZZiCPjVYxkqvcqaEhaF/0).

Comment: Pls. see my second suggestion. I think it's better (easier to read).